# Can I eliminate nested synchronized on a private field within synchronized method

Tags: java, concurrency, synchronized, jcstress

I've got this legacy pseudocode:

```java
public class Wrapper {
  private volatile Sink sink;

  public synchronized void flushSink() {
    if (sink != null) {
      synchronized (sink) {
        sink.flush();
      }
    }
  }

  public void close()  throws IOException {
    var sink = this.sink;
    if (sink != null) {
      sink.receivedLast();
    }
  }
}
```

My question is about nested `synchronized` block.

As far as I understand the mentioned block is redundant in this case, as if two threads concurrently call `flushSink()`, then only one of them has access to private field `sink` at a time. As a result the code could be simplified to

```java
public class Wrapper {
  private volatile Sink sink;

  public synchronized void flushSink() {
    if (sink != null) {
      sink.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

with possible further elimination of racy read into

```java
public class Wrapper {
  private volatile Sink sink;

  public synchronized void flushSink() {
    var sink = this.sink;
    if (sink != null) {
      sink.flush();
    }
  }
}
```

So my question is whether this kind of refactoring correct in terms of synchronization and JMM and if it is (alternatively if it is not) - is there any JCStress-based test proving it?

Comment: So unless there's some other way to access/modify `sink`, outside of synchronization on the containing `Wrapper` instance (e.g. other methods in `Wrapper` that aren't synchronized), the inner synchronization block doesn't make sense.  As to the "elimination of racy reads", your synchronized methods are already doing that.

Comment: I think you did not provide the complete code snippet - how is the `sink` attribute set?

Comment: @AdamSiemion the code of `flushSink()` method is full, no other logic in that method

Comment: @SergeyTsypanov i meant `Wrapper` class

Comment: The code is not full, how does `sink` get initialized? @SergeyTsypanov

Comment: It's initialized in constructor and set to null in close method, updated the snippet. Pay attention, that `close()` is not synchronized.

Comment: We'd need to see the constructor, otherwise the code you're changing might be wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found open source code exactly repeating the case, see `java.io.PipedOutputStream`:

```java
@Override
public synchronized void flush() throws IOException {
    if (sink != null) {
        synchronized (sink) {
            sink.notifyAll();
        }
    }
}
```

The code looks exactly like the snippet I was investigating, and if I do the same refactoring `PipedOutputStream`-related JDK tests will fail.

The transformation is illegal, because `synchronized` on `flush()` method assumes locking on `this` i.e. on `PipedOutputStream` object, and `synchronized (sink)` locks on another object. Thus we have two different locks and lock coarsening is not allowed in this case.

Answer (score 1):

> As far as I understand the mentioned block is redundant in this case, as if two threads concurrently call flushSink(), then only one of them has access to private field sink at a time. As a result the code could be simplified to

It is redundant as long as there is no other place in the code where `sink` is accessed within a synchronized block.

For instance, if the `close()` method were changed to the following,

```
public void close()  throws IOException {
  var sink = this.sink;
  if (sink != null) {
    synchronized(sink) {
      sink.receivedLast();
    }
  }
}
```

then the synchronized block in `flushSink()` would not be useless as it would ensure that `receivedLast()` and `flush()` are not being called at the same time.